# How to validate Quiz Questions Form Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a pretty basic form that shows quiz questions along with choices:

```
<%= form_tag(quiz_attempts_path, :method =>'post') %>
    <% @course_step.step.step_quiz.step_quiz_questions.each do |quiz_question| %>
        <h3><%= quiz_question.value %></h3>

        <% quiz_question.step_quiz_question_choices.each do |quiz_question_choice| %>
        <%= radio_button_tag("quiz_questions[#{quiz_question.id}]", quiz_question_choice.value, false)%>
        <%= quiz_question_choice.value%><br />
        <% end %>

    <% end %>
    <%= hidden_field_tag('step_quiz_id', @course_step.step.step_quiz.id)%>
    <%= hidden_field_tag('started', Time.now.utc)%>
    <%= submit_tag("Submit Quiz")%>
</form>
```

When I save the result for the form, I only save summary data: (Do I need to validate the data coming in to this method with some sort of model?)

```
def create
    correct = 0
    incorrect = 0
    params[:quiz_questions].each do |step_quiz_question_id, chosen_answer|
      if StepQuizQuestion.find(step_quiz_question_id).correct?(chosen_answer)
        correct += 1
      else
        incorrect += 1
      end
    end

    QuizAttempt.create(:patient_id => current_user.id, :correct => correct, :incorrect => incorrect, :started => params[:started], :ended => Time.now, :step_quiz_id => params[:step_quiz_id])
  end
```

Below is my quiz attempt model that I am saving to.

```
class QuizAttempt < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :step_quiz
  belongs_to :patient

  attr_accessible :step_quiz_id, :patient_id, :started, :ended, :correct, :incorrect  
end


# == Schema Information
#
# Table name: quiz_attempts
#
#  id           :integer         not null, primary key
#  step_quiz_id :integer
#  patient_id   :integer
#  started      :datetime
#  ended        :datetime
#  correct      :integer
#  incorrect    :integer
#  created_at   :datetime
#  updated_at   :datetime
#
```

**How would you validate the form without doing a lot of code?**

**Is my general approach to this correct?**

Comment: Do these kinds of validation in the models, it will make your controller cleaner and more maintainable :)

Comment: @rubyfanatic How would you validate this in a model which doesn't contain the question data? (just summary data) See above model

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think a better approach could be the nested fields approach.

You can have a very good start on this [here (part 1)](http://railscasts.com/episodes/196-nested-model-form-part-1) and [here (part 2)](http://railscasts.com/episodes/197-nested-model-form-part-2)
with exactly your scenario, a survey with questions and answers.

For the validation you need to provide more information for what kind of validation you need.

Comment: I am using nested fields for the backend part of the survey (actually used that railscast!), but now I am stuck on the frontend part (where the user takes the survey). Since my data model of storing a quiz result is very different than what I display to the user, I am having a hard time validating that all the questions are filled in. I have updated my question with relevant models

Comment: So you need to validate that in a QuizAttempt all the questions have been answered and not left blank. Correct?

Comment: Well a quiz attempt doesn't have the questions, just summary data. (see above model) it would be correct that I want to make sure all the questions are filled in.

Comment: I guess I could create a virtual attribute quiz_questions and validate that, which would work!